# Series of integrable functions converges pointwise almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I need some help, solving the following problem I found in my textbook. **QUESTIONS APPEAR IN BOLD CAPITALS**.

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) be a sequence of integrable functions such that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X |f_n| \mathrm{d}\mu < \infty.$$
>
> Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges almost everywhere to an integrable function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ and 
>   $$ \int_X f \mathrm{d}\mu = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_X f_n \mathrm{d}\mu.$$

I know that monotonous convergence gives me
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X |f_n| \mathrm{d}\mu =\int_X  \sum_{n=1}^\infty  |f_n| \mathrm{d}\mu,$$
i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  |f_n|$ is integrable.
Integrability of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  |f_n|$ gives me that this series converges almost everywhere.
Hence, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n(x)|$ converges, also $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges. This implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges almost everywhere to some $f$.

Furthermore, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n|$ a majorant for $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty  f_n|$ and since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is measurable as the limit of measurable functions this gives the integrability of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$.

**WHY IS $f$ MEASURABLE?** (*I think, this won't be the case if the measure space is not assumed to be complete. Am I right? But in case the measure space IS complete, I am good to go on.*)

If I have this, then $f$ would be integrable as well, because it almost everywhere equals an integrable function.

This implies
$$\int_X f\mathrm{d}\mu = \int_X \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \mathrm{d}\mu.$$
**BUT WHY IS THIS EQUAL TO $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_X  f_n \mathrm{d}\mu$?**

Comment: So in the first question, you want to know why a function is measurable if it's almost everywhere equal to a measurable function?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, since the problem as far as I know does NOT assume completeness of the measure space.

Comment: @Timkinsella: Well, in general this is not possible. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307044/measurability-of-a-function-almost-equivalent-to-a-measurable-function.
But maybe the setting of this problem still allows this conclusion.

Comment: I think sometimes people assume a completion has been taken without stating it explicitly.  As you probably know, you can always complete a measure.

Comment: For your other question, I think you can just use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Timkinsella: Of course... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can define $f(x)$ as $\lim_{N\to  +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$ when the  series  $\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$ converges and $0$ otherwise. In this case, the function $f$ is measurable since the set of convergence of a series of measurable functions is measurable and $\sum_{n=1}^N f_n\to f$ almost everywhere.

For the last question, as Tim kinsella suggests, you can use the dominated convergence theorem applied to the sequence $g_N$ defined by $\sum_{n=1}^N f_n$ and the dominating function $g:=\sum_{n=1}^N \left|f_n\right|$.