# Prove sum of functions is $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $\| f_n\|_{L^2} \leq 2^{-k}, $ where $L^2$ represents the banach space of squared integrable  functions, and $g:= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_n|,$ I need to show that $g \in L^2,$ i.e. $\int |g|^2 d\mu < \infty.$

I first thought to use the Hölder inequality for $f_1 =g, f_2 = g.$
$$\int g \,g \,d \mu \leq (\int (|f_1| + |f_2| +...)^2)^{1/2} \,\,(\int (|f_1| + |f_2| +...)^2)^{1/2}.$$ But this is not leading to anything. It is clear that the geometric series $\sum 2^{-k}$ converges.

Can somebody provide any suggestion or solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925336/series-of-l2-functions-converges-pointwise-almost-everywhere

Comment: Do you know that $L^2$ is complete?

Comment: use riesz fischer and dominated convergence

Comment: Thanks. Given that $L^2$ is complete, can one conclude that $g \in L^2 $ only from the fact that $ \forall k, f_{n_k} \in L^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

By monotone convergence theorem,
$$\lVert g \rVert_{L^2} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\left\lVert \sum_{k = 1}^{N}|f_n|\right\rVert_{L^2} \leq \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\lVert f_n \rVert_{L^2} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\lVert f \rVert_{L^2} < \infty.$$